# Scala I would like to compare two list and list of wrapped elementes

Tags: scala

I have two collection variables one is with list of elements and another one is list of wrappedarray elements.

input:

```
val fst = List(WrappedArray(Apple, Graps))
val sec= List(Graps, Banana,Mango,Apple)
```

Expected output would be, in variable fst elements we have to check with sec variable elements if all the elements from fst present in sec then it should show matching else not matched.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't

```
fst.flatten.forall (sec.contains (_))
```

do the trick?
To lazy to set up a bunch of fruits, I helped myself with Strings:

```
val a = Array ("Graps", "Apple")   
val wa: WrappedArray[String] = a   
val fst = List(wa)   
val sec= List("Graps", "Banana", "Mango", "Apple")    
fst.flatten.forall (sec.contains (_))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. i run the code in fst list we have graps,apple both are present in sec list so here i need to get true but i am getting false plz kindly help

Comment: its giving me true @Mahi

Comment: here fst declared as Array ("Graps", "Apple") but my senario i can get List(WrappedArray("Graps", "Apple")) how can i change wrappedArray

Comment: No, "a" is declared as Array, wa as WrappedArray and fst as List(wa). You can copy that code into a REPL and see: `scala> val fst = List(wa)   
fst: List[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]] = List(WrappedArray(Graps, Apple))`